# How to add custom buttons to a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

So as my question states, I'm trying to add custom buttons to a `UINavigationBar`. AFAIK, you can only add a `leftbutton` and a `rightbutton`. However, I want to add 2 more, 1 on each side of the title. Is there any way to do this? :)

Comment: Just checked it out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add more buttons to both sides by accessing the following:

1. create programatically the buttons that you want.
2. get a reference to the navigationitem buttons array
3. add the buttons to the array like this:

   ```
   rightAddButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)]; 

   editButtonItem = ....; 

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem,rightAddButton,nil];
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Other than what you mentioned, `UINavigationItem` has two more properties called `leftBarButtonItems` and `rightBarButtonItems`. You can use those properties to add multiple items.

Always suggest developers to loop up the documentation.

Comment: Hey Lucas! Thanks for your answer! I've been doing that but I didn't realize you could add more than one to them. Check Anbu's comment! :)